# General purpose database application alternatives for iOS and Mac

Tags: osx, ios, database, cross-platform, spreadsheet

I am looking for a way to manage inventory in the field.  I want to use an ipad/iphone for taking inventory, and use a mac to generate reports.

This can be a single app or a pair of apps.

I can do some of what I want now using Google Spreadsheet and GAS (Google application script)  However Google docs do ***NOT*** run scripts offline.  I have no internet access where I'm taking inventory.  (The nearest wifi  is a thousand feet away.)

I can do this with Filemaker Pro.  But that seems like bringing 16" guns to bear on a mouse sized problem.  FM is uncheap.

I might be able to do it on Excel for iPad, but I'm incensed by Microsloths licensing policy for iOS apps, so I've not looked at this directly.

In a spreadsheet style application the functions I need:

- take action on edit.
- indirect lookups.
- filter as a command
- arrayformula

In a database style application I need the ability to edit in table view, do filtering, lookups, dropdown lists filled by filter commands.

Ideas?

Comment: What kind of scripting that you do with your inventory database?

Comment: To be useful in the field, I need chained lookups.  E.g. the elements of lookup box B is dependent on the choice made from box A.  Then the lookups in C are dependent on what was eventually chosen in B.  This is easy to do in google sheets.

Comment: Have you tried Tap Forms? I suppose it can do this with linked tables?

Comment: The beginning of your second sentence is garbled. Also, please use italics instead of ALL-CAPS. The markdown for italics is: Surround with an asterisk on each side.

Answer (score 1):

[Tap Forms 5](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tap-forms-5/id1081981112?mt=12&at=10lvzo&ct=SEDB) should fit your needs.

- Lookup fields are supported.
- Filters are present.
- You can create custom forms.
- Fields can be custom formulas.